# How to use HTML to validate a date range?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Alternatively, *is it possible to validate against another field's value with HTML?*

A common example would be selecting a date range where "from" date should be less than or equal to "to" date. The following would described the desired relationship between the values, if only you could use element references in syntax:

```
<input type="date" name="from" max="to">    //todo: populate with ~to.value
<input type="date" name="to" min="from">    //todo: populate with ~from.value
```

Comment: `min` and `max` attrs are the `date` format, not element\

Comment: @EL: I'm aware of the limitation (or, rather, spec restricting values to an ISO format), the example was intended to serve as pseudo-markup showing the desired relationship between the values. I've updated it to [hopefully] remove the ambiguity, thanks!

Comment: The easy way to do it is to have one date picker and one 'number of days' control.

Comment: <input id=from oninput="to.min=this.value"><input id=to oninput="from.max=this.value">

Comment: @dandavis: hmm... not everyone is a fan of inlining javascript anymore, but something along these lines could be more terse and doesn't require a bloated library. If you make this into an answer, perhaps with a working jsfiddle, this would be worth at least an upvote

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to utilize html5 validation mechanism with some javascript to dynamically update `min`/`max` attributes:

```
//in this case a single input restriction is sufficient to validate the form:

$('#from, #to').on('change', function(){
    $('#to').attr('min', $('#from').val());
});
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/GS98P/2/). Both `min` and `max` could be applied to the respective fields for enhanced UX if browser implementation of a datepicker respects range limitations (by disabling dates outside of the desired range)

Answer (score 3):

Here, [Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/) are very useful, however they are not full supported in all browsers yet .

The idea is to create a simple html Element, with two children (from and to) as the following:

```
<div id="fromToDate">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

then create a template, which defines how the date picker should look:

```
<template id="fromToDateTemplate">
    <label for="fromDate">from</label>
    <input type="date" class="fromDate" select=":first" required="" />
    <label for="toDate">to</label>
    <input type="date" class="toDate" select=":last" required="" />
</template>
```

the select parameter defines, where the value is taken from so the first input field takes the first div from the "#fromToDate".

Last we have to populate the "shadow root" and define the logic:

```
var shadow = document.querySelector('#fromToDate').webkitCreateShadowRoot(),
    template = document.querySelector('#fromToDateTemplate');
shadow.appendChild(template.content);


shadow.querySelector(".fromDate").addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    var to = this.value;

    shadow.querySelector(".toDate").setAttribute("min", this.value);
});

template.remove();
```

In the end two input fields are renderd and when selecting a date in the first datepicker, the second datepicker can't pick any lower data.

Fiddler example: http://jsfiddle.net/cMS9A/

Advantages:

- Build as widget
- Easy to reause
- won't break pages
- can be styled independently

Disadvantages:

- Not supported in all browsers yet

Future reading:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/
- https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/explainer/index.html

Comment: Interesting direction, but IMHO this is not something for my scenario since same logic could be replicated without shadow DOM or the cross-browser restrictions it comes with. It looks like shadow DOM is more suitable for intermediary logic though, e.g. if you had separate legacy inputs for date/month/year, these could be "wrapped" into an `input[type=date]` (spoiler alert: if you inspect the sample jsfiddle, it's DOM shows the "original" markup).

Comment: I have to agree with you. The fact that is is not supported in all browses doesn't make this a good choice for production, also the concept of shadow DOM is not widely known yet, so a solution your solution with jQuery might be better for now. A built in HTML5 feature doesn't exist in my opinion, since HTML treats each DOM element independently, for establishing a connection between them, you have JavaScript. With my solution you are not dependent on any third party library and can reuse it, so I had to share it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid issues with someone hacking / crashing yor site - validate input data with:

- (**optional**) javascript before sending a form (protects against malforming data using javascript, inputting incorrect one, reduces traffic)
- (**mandatory**) on server side  (protects against more clever guys that might malform input data using fiddler for example)

This is the only (at least second point) approach that protects you and your site.

Comment: I don't know why this has been downvoted, it's never a bad idea to point out the need for server-side validation whenever client-side validation is discussed. My intention is, however, to improve the UX of genuine (non-malicious) users; if you look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/GS98P/2/) from [my original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19239320/1081234) you'll notice that after a "from" date is selected you can no longer pick an "after" date before it - native datepicker elements respect the `min` restriction and disables dates before it.

Answer (score 0):

It's great to see things moving towards a pure HTML solution ... but why not take a look at using moment.js to fill in the gaps for the time being?

http://momentjs.com/

There are plenty of good examples there and a lot of useful utility methods.

Comment: I'm already using momentjs for a few things (because date manipulation and formatting without a framework sucks in JS), but I fail to see how this would help with min/max for datepickers.

Comment: Cool. I was pointing towards using something like this: https://github.com/gf3/moment-range

Answer (score -1):

I'm worry, that there's no chance how to validate a input value based on other input value. Only good old javascript.

But maybe you can use `<input type="range" …>` and set some minimal step (1 day / 1 hour / …). Then you can use `min` and `max` value by same-named attributes.

Comment: How is one supposed to use [`<input type="range" ...>`](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/input-type-range.html) for picking a date?