# Handling From and To date in jquery/javascript for dynamic loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I have a for loop that will run five times. First condition is to check whether there is `from_date` and `to_date` in it.
If yes validate the from and to date and throw error message is to date is less than the from date.

I know that i need to get the `$i` value of each text box and validate but with no clue.

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) { ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group date" id="from_date_<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="from_date_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" value=<?php echo $from_date; ?> >
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group date" id="to_date_<?php echo $i; ?>" >
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="to_date_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $to_date; ?>" >
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Also, I have checked the stackoverflow questions but there is no validation for dynamic rows.
http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/SWQme/
[How to use HTML5 to validate a date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239319/how-to-use-html5-to-validate-a-date-range)

Comment: So you have an input-form with 5x2 dates. And when the user submits the form, you want to validate everything with php? Or do you want to validate the values, that you will insert as default-values?

Comment: So you have an input-form with 5x2 dates. And when the user submits the form, you want to validate everything with php - YES, you are right maja

Comment: Then you can't write it this way. The user enters the data, and clicks "submit". And then the browser loads a different page. You have to validate the inputs in that page. If you want validation without reloading the page (eg. to print error-messages), you have to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: On the site, where the browser is redirected after the submit, you can validate the GET- (or POST) Parameters which will contain the inserted values

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be a big deal:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var from = new Date(document.querySelector('[name=from_date_' + i + ']').value);
  var to = new Date(document.querySelector('[name=to_date_' + i + ']').value);
 if (from - to >= 0) {
    // bad
 }
}
```