# set the input type = date min from another input type = date

Tags: php, html

Hi i'm a rookie in html and been struggling in this inputs,

```
<label>Check-In Date :  </label>
<input id ="date1" type="date" name="from" min=<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));;?>>    
<label>Check-Out Date : </label>
<input id = "date2" type="date" name="to">
```

i just want to know how to set the second input minimum date from the first input selected value? i've already searched and i just can't get the right 
answer...

Comment: ill try it sir..

Comment: To achieve this i would recommend using jQuery. You would add an event listener on the `date2` field being clicked which would get the value from the `date1`.

Comment: @jayrbayog use jquery

Comment: PHP is server-side script. So it will only run on the server. You should use client-side script like JavaScript, jQuery, etc. This can be run when the user does *something* without having to request anything else from your server.

Comment: how would i implement that sir?

Comment: [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup) and [How to add jQuery code into HTML Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796169/how-to-add-jquery-code-into-html-page)

Comment: @LewisBrowne I wouldn't suggest doing it when it's clicked. A user could tab over to that field to change it instead of selecting it with the cursor. A better method would be to use `focus` instead of click. Or even better would be to change the value when date1 is `change`-d

Comment: @ctwheels this code is not working: $('input[name="from"]').change(function(){$('input[name="to"‌​]').val($(this).val(‌​));})

Comment: @ctwheels Yeah that makes sense. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTML5 to validate a date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239319/how-to-use-html5-to-validate-a-date-range)

Comment: i just found a solution base on @LewisBrowne idea; i added onclick="setDate2();" on date2 and  function setDate2() {
    document.getElementById('date2').min =  document.getElementById('date1').value;
  }, it works fine...

Comment: It won't work if you tab to it. Just use the code I provided in the answer, it'll work for *any* (almost) change events that occur on `input[name='from']`. I had a typo in the original response I gave in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is server-side script that only runs on the server (not on the client). For a more detailed explanation of client-side vs server-side scripting please view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

---

To accomplish what you want, you would use client-side script like JavaScript you can easily achieve this.

Below is jQuery that will update the second field whenever the first field is changed.

**jQuery**

```
$("input[name='from']").change(function() {
  $("input[name='to']").val($(this).val());
})
```

Make sure to include jQuery so that the above loads: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: maybe that's my problem, i didn't include ajax

Comment: yeah sir this code works, but i need to change the minimum value not the actual value.

Comment: i tried this, $("input[name='from']").change(function() {
  $("input[name='to']").min($(this).val()); but it is not working

Comment: Use the `attr` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316709/how-to-set-the-max-value-and-min-value-of-input-in-html5-by-javascript-or-jque

Comment: ahh, okay. great. Thank you sir. follow up question. can i set the label on php??

Comment: PHP is used to generate HTML. So yes you can edit the label in PHP. You can edit anything you send the client using PHP